# Unity Rigidbody's Velocity is zero but Object still moves

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm in the progress of writing a script for moving a player. A smooth motion along the x-axis is intended. Everything worked fine but when i wrote some code to slowly stop the player, some weird behavior emerged. The spaceship never comes to a complete stop, but rather shakes at the spot.

So first of all, Iknow that the documentation say's, that what I'm doing here isn't good:

> In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly, as this can result in unrealistic behaviour.

Still I wanted to ask if anybody knows why this is happening, or how I can avoid using `rb.velocity *= BREAKING_FACTOR;` in my code. (In the rigidbodys inspector velocity jumps from 0 to 0.04 and back every frame).

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private const float MAX_SPEED = 8f, FORCE_FACTOR = 20f, BREAKING_FACTOR = .9f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private void Start () { rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> (); }
    private void Update () 
    {
        var inputDirection = new Vector2 (0f, 0f);

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A) && rb.velocity.x > -MAX_SPEED) 
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (-1f, 0f);
        else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D) && rb.velocity.x < MAX_SPEED)
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (1f, 0f);
        else 
        {
            // rb.velocity *= BREAKING_FACTOR;

            // If no force is added on the x-asis, the spaceship shall slow down
            if (rb.velocity.x > 0f) 
                inputDirection += new Vector2 (-1, 0);
            else if (rb.velocity.x < 0f) 
                inputDirection += new Vector2 (1, 0);               

            // Get it to stop completely when very slow
            if (Mathf.Abs (rb.velocity.x) < 1f) 
                // The Thing you shouldn't do:
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        rb.AddForce (inputDirection * FORCE_FACTOR);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the velocity is below a certain threshold, you can get away with setting the velocity directly.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a month old, but maybe I can still help you.

First of all, here are a few general tips on avoiding direct velocity modification:

-You can avoid the direct modification with the "BREAKING_FACTOR" by using the 'drag' variable of the Rigidbody.
Setting it to a value higher than 0 constantly slows down your Rigidbody, but constantly setting the velocity will keep it moving without slowing down, so that would really help you I think.
-To avoid movement while constantly setting the velocity, you should make sure you have disabled gravity.
-.AddForce() is always a good way to apply a force without modifying the velocity directly.

You said that the veloctiy jitters, it would be helpful to have some more information about that.
But I think the problem lies in this snippet:

```
        if (rb.velocity.x > 0f) 
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (-1, 0);
        else if (rb.velocity.x < 0f) 
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (1, 0);       

        // Get it to stop completely when very slow
        if (Mathf.Abs (rb.velocity.x) < 1f) 
            // The Thing you shouldn't do:
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, rb.velocity.y);
```

You are always applying a force on your object, because of that, the x velocity will never be zero, and one of the two cases will always happen.
You could fix that by either changing the way you slow it down (for example by multiplying the velocity by 0.9f like you did with the breaking) by adding a treshold 
(the code could look something like this)

```
        if (rb.velocity.x > 0.1f) 
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (-1, 0);
        else if (rb.velocity.x < -0.1f) 
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (1, 0);
```

(but without a drag the spaceship would just jitter slower that way)
or (and that's the way I would do it) by just leaving this code out of the script and adding a drag (I mentioned that earlier) to the rigidbody.

So in the end I think it's the drag that you need. Then you can get rid of this whole part

```
        // If no force is added on the x-asis, the spaceship shall slow down
        if (rb.velocity.x > 0f) 
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (-1, 0);
        else if (rb.velocity.x < 0f) 
            inputDirection += new Vector2 (1, 0);               

        // Get it to stop completely when very slow
        if (Mathf.Abs (rb.velocity.x) < 1f) 
            // The Thing you shouldn't do:
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, rb.velocity.y);
```

because it makes your Rigidbody jitter.

I hope this helped you
-Julian-